# What code to put in the URL to link it in a new tab?

Tags: url, pdf, hyperlink, links, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a PDF file. Created from Kingsoft Presentation. I have images there, where I put hyperlinks. That is Ctrl+K then i put the link. When I converted it to PDF ang click the images, I want it to open in a new tab. How could i do that. Sample: Here's the link I put in the hyperlink on the image. And unfortunately, it open in the same tab. http://onwardprocess.com/improvesalesstrategy-appointment/

Ok, I will update my question here.

What if I used this link ->
https://twitter.com/intent/session?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwebprojectupdates.com%2Fonwardprocess%2F&related=sharethis&return_to=%2Fintent%2Ftweet%3Ftext%3DImprove%2520Sales%2520Strategy%253A%252011%2520Ways%2520to%2520get%2520off%2520the%2520sales%252

So that I could tweet something, but the question is, what will I add to this hyperlink for it to be open in a new tab. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put target attribute in hyperlink.

Here is a sample code:

```
 <a href="YOUR LINK HERE" target="_blank">YOUR LINK TEXT</a>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the update, but can we actually put that <a> tag on Kingsoft Presentation hyperlink?

Comment: After you insert the hyper link, you can set the action. Please have a look at [documentation](http://www.kingsoftstore.com/download/presentation-2012-user-manual.pdf) at page no. 18.

Comment: Okay then, what will I put in the hyperlink? The same url? Still, it will not open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

The target attribute specifies where to open the linked document:

```
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

Comment: I think you didn't get the question. Im not talking about HTML tags here. Im talking about a URL.

Comment: Please follow this [link] http://www.ehow.com/how_4707191_hyperlink-pdf-file.html